# Is it possible to change page urls in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to change the collections page urls  from  https://www.product.com/collections/view/14e92dd34fb680e94c02e9ebd2ce36b29e92fd8a-*4*75 this like below http://www.product.com/larimar-jewelry/abril-necklace we do not want any random text in the urls. in codeigniter

Comment: use  codeigniter routing

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

You can set your alias in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['alias-value'] = 'controller/method';
```

refer documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Otherwise you can do this with rewrite rule using .htaccess file.

Please refer [doc](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)